# вывести только уникальные записи с сообщениями

Tags: python, django

не могу вывести только уникальные записи с сообщениями в виде диалогов из бд

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, 
        related_name="sender",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, 
        related_name="reciever",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,) 
    msg_content = models.TextField(null='True')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Postings"
```

views.py

```
def message(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pass
        else:
            dialoge_list = Message.objects.filter(sender=request.user)
            for x in dialoge_list:
                print("от пользователя: ",x.reciever.first_name, "id:",x.reciever.id)
            return render(request, 'board/message.html', {'dialoge_list':dialoge_list})
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

результат из консоли

```
от пользователя:  ФЕДЯ id: 43  
от пользователя:  ФЕДЯ id: 43   
от пользователя:  саша id: 46   
от пользователя:  тестовый id: 50
```

уникальность должна заключаться в id пользователей. не могу сделать, чтобы результат был id 43, 46, 50

Comment: ну создай еще список или множество, перед выводом проверяй, есть ли id  в списке, после вывода добавляй новый id в список.

Comment: всё сделал как ты мне посоветовал 
Эникейщик всё норм работает теперь